# How to post javascript form using jsoup?

Tags: javascript, java, forms, jsoup

I want to extract some data from http://www.wettportal.com/quotenarchiv/.

There is a javascript form:
[Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGTtk.png)

```
<form id="archivesearchform" name="archivesearchform" method="post" action="">
...
<td class="ralign">Sportart:</td>
<td>
<select name="sport_id" id="sport_id" style="width:100%">
...
<td class="ralign">Land:</td>
<td>
<select name="region_id" id="region_id" style="width:100%;">
...
<td class="ralign">Liga:</td>
<td>
<select name="league_id" id="league_id" style="width:100%">
...
<td class="ralign">vom:</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="fromdate" id="fromdate" style="width:100%" />
...
<td class="ralign">vom:</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="fromdate" id="fromdate" style="width:100%" />
</td>
<td class="ralign">bis:</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="tilldate" id="tilldate" style="width:100%" />
</td>
<td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ralign">Teilnehmer:</td>
<td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="team" style="width:100%" /></td>
<td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

and the submit-button:

```
<tr>
<td class="lalign"></td>
<td class="calign"><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Suchen" /></td>
<td class="ralign"><div class="loading-animation" id="div_loading"></div></td>
</tr>
```

I try it with this code:

```
import java.io.IOException; 

import org.jsoup.Jsoup; 
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document; 
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element; 
import org.jsoup.select.Elements; 

public class QAJesoupE { 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        try { 
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.wettportal.com/quotenarchiv/")
                .data("sport_id", "4")
                .data("region_id", "16")
                .data("league_id", "0")
                .data("fromdate", "")
                .data("tilldate", "")
                .data("team", "")
                // and other hidden fields which are being passed in post request.
                .userAgent("Mozilla")
                .post();
                System.out.println(doc); // will print html source of homepage of facebook.

        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
    } 
}
```

But I get only the HTML code without any search results. :-/

Could please anyone help me?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a script on this site that handles the *form submit*. Even if the `form` element defines a `POST`, the script actually sends a `get` request with the data as URL parameters:

```
http://www.wettportal.com/lib/ajax/getArchivedEvents.php?partner=wettportal&lang=de&sport_id=4&region_id=23&league_id=0&fromdate=&tilldate=&team=
```

*Jsoup* will create the request URL (with parameters) for you, but you will have to send a `GET` request and include the `X-Requested-With` header (see below):

```
Document doc = Jsoup
    .connect("http://www.wettportal.com/lib/ajax/getArchivedEvents.php")
    .data("sport_id", "4")
    .data("region_id", "16")
    .data("league_id", "0")
    .data("fromdate", "")
    .data("tilldate", "")
    .data("team", "")
    .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
    .timeout(10000)
    .get();
```

Comment: @Kosta that's simple, open *Firebug* or *Chrome Dev Tools* and click on the *Network* tab. When you submit the form, you will see what the browser sends to the server.

Comment: Really THANKS A LOT  for your support!